# What happen when I do wordQuery on joined views

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I have to join this views:

```
const employees = op.fromView('main', 'employees');
const expenses = op.fromView('main', 'expenses');

const Plan =
  employees.joinInner(expenses, op.on(employees.col('EmployeeID'),
                      expenses.col('EmployeeID')))
           .where(op.gt(expenses.col('Amount'), 150))
           .select([employees.col('EmployeeID'), 'FirstName',
                    'LastName', expenses.col('Amount')]);
```

And want to perform wordQuery on this Plan to get correct result.

```
Plan.where(cts.wordQuery(keyword)).result();
```

What documents will this where affect?